# How to get a part of an image out and use it as a mask on the image in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an image. It is a glass tube and in the middle with shaft tube stirring the liquid in the glass tube.

I would like to contour the stirring tube in the middle out and analyze only the rest of the image. I tried to use contour from OpenCV. This is what I got. But I only want to contour the shaft tube out. It didn't do what I intended to do.

[image: 1]
[image: contour result]

Here is the code I used:

```
img_path = "For_stack.png"
image = cv2.imread(img_path)
image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("original", image_gray)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(image_gray, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow("binary image", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("image_thresh1.png", thresh)
```

Comment: what makes you think that picture is usable? why does the entire scene look red?

Comment: Hey Christoph. Thank you for your reply. 

I don't know if the picture is suitable for what I want or not. I hope it does. The red is from the red light I used when I shot the video.